# Why can TexStudio crash when adding a word to the dictionary?

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

TexStudio crashed when I added a word to the dictionary.
I cannot reproduce this error, and I couldn't find another question concerning this topic but why did TexStudio crash?

Comment: see if you can find the backtrace log file, TXS creates in such cases. it's usually in the temp folder.

Comment: thanks! The problem has not occured again, I'm going to keep this in mind the next time it happens